# How to join hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I want to achieve something like this :

```
feeds = []
following_companies.each do |follow|
  feeds = feeds + Activities.where(:company_id => follow.company_id).order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
end
feeds = feeds.order("created_at DESC")
```

By the point I use `feeds = feeds.order("created_at DESC")`, `feeds` its  an Array and throws an exception saying `undefined method order for #<Array:0x007f78032e2458>`. As long as I know the `where` clause returns a hash ( or an ActiveRecord list, please correct me if I am wrong).  I think the problem is the way I am initializing `feeds`. Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you throw the limit on the end of the where clause, it returns an array instead of Arel. You could sort the array instead of using the arel method `order`.

```
 feeds = feeds.sort{|f| f.created_at }
```

**Update**
If the following companies is still a query you can do

```
company_ids = following_companies.pluck(:company_id)
```

If it is an array, you can do this to get all the company_ids

```
company_ids = following_companies.map {|u| u.location_id }
```

You can do one query, instead of looping through, for all the feeds which will be

```
Activities.where(company_id: company_ids).order("created_at DESC")
```

I'm not sure how you would limit it to 5 for each id though.

Answer (score 1):

`feeds.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse` will do this directly on feeds after you're done building it with your loop, but you need to do this more efficiently in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing above is going to generate a ton of queries if you have any considerable number of followed companies.  I'm not sure what your models looks like, but what I can glean from above is something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

You should be able to add a relationship on User to allow you to query all activities at once.  Your user model would like something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  has_many :activities, through: :companies
end
```

Then you'd be able to gather your activities by doing `user.activities`, which would use a join to capture all of the activities, only generating one query.  Obviously, your data model may not look exactly like this, but this is the general gist of it.